# I can't make my video background work in my HTML page

Tags: html, css

English isn't my first language, so forgive me if I have grammatical hicups or spelling mistakes, I'm still learning.

As the title says, my video background isn't working and I don't know where the issue lies exactly. I have already tried to apply some of the solutions I found on the internet but nothing works. If any of you could spare some time to look at my code I'd appreciate it.

OBS: I'm using VS Code and the video is saved in an internal folder within the project, as referenced in the CSS. The connection between CSS and HTML is correct, I tested it.

HTML:

```
<!--início da section-apresentação-->
      <section class="section-apresentacao">
        <div id="div-video">
          <video autoplay muted loop id="meuVideo">
            <source src="./videos/Marvel Studio.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
        </div>
      </section>
    <!--fim da section-apresentação-->
```

CSS:

```
#div-video {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}    

#meuVideo {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: `height: 100%;` only works if the parent has a fixed defined height not a calculated height to fit content. However the whole solution itself is way to "difficault". The easiest solution is to use `element { position: fixed; inset: 0; }` to let it cover the whole page. You can then push it into the background by using a negative z-index like: `element { z-index: -1; }`

Comment: This won't work on IE11, but who cares... Use -> width: 100%; aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;